# I allocate memory for a Pair object but fail to place the object there

Tags: c++

I would like to have a dynamic array of pointers to pointers to Pair elements;

```
int m_size = 0;
Pair** ar = new Pair*[++m_size];
*ar[0] = Pair(key, data);
```

Here I get:
Unhandled exception at 0x013729db in lab3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcdcdcdcd.

It happened in the overloaded operator for MyString (HERE marks when the exception threw):

```
MyString & MyString::operator = (const MyString & refMyString){
HERE: this->m_pStr = refMyString.m_pStr;
    return *this;
}
```

My classes (a bit simplified for our purpose):

```
class Pair{
    MyString m_key;
    Data* m_data;
}


class MyString
{
    char* m_pStr;
}
```

And here is what I get in the debugger:

http://sdrv.ms/ZwkZ9P

http://sdrv.ms/17eoGp6

Well, as far as I can see, when I did Pair** ar = new Pair*[++m_size], a new pointer to pointer to a space for a Pair instance was created. But it is just space in memory. And when I try to operate it, I fail.

And what to do is a mystery to me. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocate an array of `Pair*` but :

1) You never initialize the pointers in that array

2) You dereference those uninitialized pointers (which point to who-knows-where) and overwrite the memory there.

No wonder you get a segfault since you're writing to unallocated memory.

What you (probably?) want to do is:

`ar[0] = new Pair(...)`

Or better yet, use a standard container (vector, list, deque, ...) instead of C arrays, that will either contain plain objects or smart pointers (unique_ptr or shared_ptr) so that you don't have to manage the memory yourself.

Comment: Well. Not working. No exception, it is good. But due to the scope of that new Pair, it disappeared at the closing bracket. So, outside this method I still have an empty array.

Comment: @Trts there must be another problem in some part of the code you didn't show, then. `new`'ed objects have dynamic lifetime, which means that they don't get destroyed automatically when you exit your current scope.

Comment: Yeah. I have found it. Working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a two dimensional array using a double pointer, you need to allocate both dimensions:

```
// allocates an array of 10 int* objects
int** p = new int*[10];

for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
{
   // Allocates an array of 3 integers
   p[0] = new int[3];
}
```

You would need to ensure that all of the objects you are creating are deleted:

```
// later
for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
   delete [] p[x];

delete [] p;
```

I would suggest however, just using `std::vector` so you don't need to manage the memory yourself:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> p;

p.resize(10);

for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
{
   p[x].resize(3);
}
```

Comment: No, vectors are forbidden so far by the lecturer.